# Login with Facebook after integrating facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

How can I integrate Login with `Facebook` in my application?  I already integrated `Facebook SDK` but I am not able to open the login activity of `Facebook`.

i try this,

```
// Your Facebook APP ID  
    private static String APP_ID = "MY_ID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });

// Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        return  view;
    }
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Which facebook sdk are you trying to integrate with?

Comment: did you declared facebook activity in your manifest

Comment: are you using eclipse or studio?

Comment: show what you have done so far @virenkheni

Comment: i am using android studio

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the complete code to get Facebook profile details... I have used Facebook SDK 4.4.0**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    URL myurl;
    String profilepic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays
                .asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        new fblogin().execute(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class fblogin extends AsyncTask<AccessToken, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(AccessToken... params) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(params[0],
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("MainActivity", response.toString());
                            try {
                                String profile_pic = object.getString("id");
                                try {
                                    myurl = new URL(
                                            "https://graph.facebook.com/"
                                                    + profile_pic + "/picture");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                profilepic = myurl.toString();


                                Log.v("Name", object.getString("first_name"));
                                Log.v("Email", object.getString("email"));
                                Log.v("Profile Pic Url", profilepic);
                                Log.v("Gender", object.getString("gender"));

                            } catch (JSONException jse) {
                                // session.logoutUser();
                                Log.e("fb json exception", jse.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,email,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(request);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    }
}
```

**In manifest file add this**

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- Just create app in Facebook and get fingerprints
- download facebook sdk and import it into your project

MainActivity

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.facebookapp.R;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private TextView username;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    username.setText("You are currently logged in as " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    username.setText("You are not logged in.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your manifest add this

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/APP_ID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it by removing `facebook sdk` and only add `dependancies compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'` and implements this code in my Login_activity

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                         Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                buttonsEnabled(true);
                //Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                buttonsEnabled(false);
                //Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
            }
        }
    };
{
if (!session.isClosed()) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                //clear your preferences if saved
}
        } 
else 
{
session = new Session(context);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved
}
}
```